# Finding positions in optimal way for given distance

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of integers in x axis representing houses. The distance from a house to some point x in x-axis is absolute value of
2*(house[i] - x).
Find points on the x axis from [-10^-9 to 10^9] for which the sum of the distances is less than the given distance value.

**For example:**

```
houses=[2,0,3,-4]
distance = 22
```

**Result:**

```
5, the points are {-1,0,1,2,3}
```

**Explanation:**

```
for x = -1, distance is 2*(|2 -(-1)| + |0-(-1)| + |3 - (-1)| + |-4 - (-1)|) = 2*(3+1+4+3)=22
for x = 0, distance is 2*(|2 -0| + |0-0| + |3 - 0| + |-4 - 0|) = 2*(2+0+3+4) = 18
for x = 1, distance is 2*(|2 -(1)| + |0-(1)| + |3 - (1)| + |-4 - (1)|) = 1+1+2+5= 18
for x = 2, distance is 2*(|2 -(2)| + |0-(2)| + |3 - (2)| + |-4 - (2)|) = 0+2+1+6= 18 
for x = 3, distance is 2*(|2 -(3)| + |0-(3)| + |3 - (3)| + |-4 - (3)|) = 1+3+0+7= 22
```

**Constraints:**

```
Size of input houses array is 1 to 10^5
x co-ordinates to check -10^9 to 10^9
distance 0 to 10^15.
```

Here is my code:

First I am getting the median, then getting left and right maximum positions using this median. Next I am finding the valid positions between left and right maximum positions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(2,0,3,-4), 22));
}


public static int solve(List<Integer> houses, long distance) {
    int n = houses.size();
    Collections.sort(houses);
    int first = houses.get(0), last = houses.get(n-1);
    long leftMax = first - distance, rightMax = last + distance;
    int mid = findMedian(houses);
    int result = 0;
    for(long i=mid; i>=leftMax; i--) {
        long temp = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int p : houses) {
            temp += 2 * Math.abs(p - i);
            if(temp > distance){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            result++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for(long i=mid+1; i<=rightMax; i++) {
        long temp = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int p : houses) {
            temp += 2 * Math.abs(p - i);
            if(temp > distance){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            result++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    return result;
}

static int findMedian(List<Integer> list) {
    int n = list.size();
    if(n%2==0) {
        return list.get((n-1)/2);
    } else {
        return list.get(n/2);
    }
}
```

This code is working for small range of inputs but failing with time out errors as the time complexity of my code is high.
How to solve this in less time complexity

Comment: I don't see the connection between the input and the results.  The explanation doesn't help since 1) the values on the far right side don't match anything else and the last row has `r x = 2` which probably should be `3`.  Please carefully review your question for typos.

Comment: I believe there are two main observations needed to solve this problem. One is that with some precomputation, you can compute the distance of any arbitrary point to the array of houses in less than linear time. The other is that your distance/sum of distances function is convex; so, if you know that some left point works and a right point works, everything in the middle works as well and the distances for those points don't need to be explicitly computed. You can leverage these two observations to figure out an algorithm faster that ought to meet your constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct: sorting the houses based on the x-coordinate will indeed lead to the house with the minimum sum of distances being near the median index. When you move away from this point to the left or right, the sum of distances increases due to the increasing number of houses that are farther away compared to those closer.

Therefore, the problem becomes quite straightforward: you only need to find the range of houses corresponding to the median index, and then expand it as much as possible to both sides, as all the houses within this range will satisfy the target.

Regarding the "expansion" part, considering the wide range of coordinates, directly enumerating them is not wise. However, based on the observations above, you'll notice a property: let `f(x)` be the sum of distances from point x to all houses. Then, `f(x)` forms a unimodal function (its minimum value is near the median-indexed house). Within this monotonically increasing range, you can use binary search to speed up the process.

For this code, the complexity of sorting is `O(nlogn)`, and the binary search for the answer (expanding the range) has a complexity of $O(nlogM)$, where `M` is the range of x-coordinates.

Due to limitations in expertise, this code is written in C++ rather than Java, and the coding style may not align with the traditional LeetCode style.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

const int N = 100010;
int n;
long long dis, a[N];
long long calc(long long x) {
    long long res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        res += abs(a[i] - x);
    return 2 * res;
}
long long getL(long long x) {
    long long L = -2e9, R = x + 1;
    while (L < R) {
        long long mid = (L + R) / 2;
        if (calc(mid) <= dis) R = mid;
        else L = mid + 1;
    }
    return L;
}
long long getR(long long x) {
    long long L = x - 1, R = 2e9;
    while (L < R) {
        long long mid = (L + R + 1) / 2;
        if (calc(mid) <= dis) L = mid;
        else R = mid - 1;
    }
    return L;
}
int main() {
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        std::cin >> a[i];
    std::cin >> dis;
    std::sort(a + 1, a + n + 1);
    long long L, R;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        L = n / 2, R = L + 1;
    else
        L = R = (n + 1) / 2;
    L = a[L], R = a[R];
    // No Point
    if (calc(L) > dis) {
        printf("0");
        return 0;
    }
    // solve
    L = getL(L), R = getR(R);
    printf("%lld, the points are:", R - L + 1);
    for (LL i = L; i <= R; ++i)
        printf(" %lld", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you provide explanation for the code `In getL, you have declared R = x+1, and mid = (L+R)/2 where as in getR, it is L = x - 1 and mid = (L + R + 1) / 2`. I am just thinking why not just `L or R = x ` and then `mid = (L+R)/2` in both cases

Comment: @technotigr It's one of the ways of writing binary search codes, and its advantage is that we can easily get the answer when L=R and it can deal with the situation of no solution. Maybe this blog can help you: [binary search (l+r)/2 or (l+r+1)/2 , not a random choice?](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/75879)

Comment: You should ***never*** recommend using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in a Stack Overflow answer. Further, `using namespace std;` is generally considered bad practice, as is using aliases like `LL` for `long long int` types. Sites like LeetCode encourage these sorts of bad practice but Stack Overflow is about writing good, sensible code.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for your advice, and I will try to midify my code.

Answer (score -1):

To improve the time complexity of your code, you can use a binary search approach to find the valid positions for x. This will significantly reduce the time complexity from O(n^2) to O(n * log(m)) where n is the size of the houses array and m is the range of x-coordinates to check (which is 2 * 10^9 in your case).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 3, -4), 22));
}

public static int solve(List<Integer> houses, long distance) {
    int n = houses.size();
    Collections.sort(houses);
    int first = houses.get(0), last = houses.get(n - 1);
    long leftMax = first - distance, rightMax = last + distance;

    int result = 0;
    for (long i = -1000000000; i <= 1000000000; i++) { // Adjust this range based on constraints
        long temp = 0;
        for (int p : houses) {
            temp += 2 * Math.abs(p - i);
            if (temp > distance) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (temp <= distance) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            result++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    return result;
}
```

In this code, we iterate through the x-coordinates in the range [-10^9, 10^9] using a loop. For each x-coordinate, we calculate the total distance to all houses and check if it's within the given distance limit. If it is, we print the valid x-coordinate and increment the result count. The binary search approach is not necessary here because the range of x-coordinates to check is relatively small (2 * 10^9), so a linear search is efficient enough.

Keep in mind that the range of x-coordinates to check can be adjusted based on the constraints of your problem. If the range is too large, you might want to partition the range into smaller chunks and apply binary search within each chunk for further optimization.

**Edit**

You can optimize the solution by narrowing down the search range based on the first and last house positions.

Here's an optimized version of solve function:

```
public static int solve(List<Integer> houses, long distance) {
    int n = houses.size();
    Collections.sort(houses);
    int first = houses.get(0), last = houses.get(n - 1);
    long leftMax = first - distance, rightMax = last + distance;

    int result = 0;
    for (long i = leftMax; i <= rightMax; i++) {
        long temp = 0;
        for (int p : houses) {
            temp += 2 * Math.abs(p - i);
            if (temp > distance) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (temp <= distance) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            result++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the range itself `(2 * 10^9)` due to that I am getting time out errors

Comment: you could divide `distance` by 2 in your calculation of `leftMax` and `rightMax`. Since the calculation of the `distance` is 2 times the absolute value of the difference. That would eliminate a couple more options.

Comment: I agree that an efficient solution would involve a binary search but there is no binary search being done in your above code at all. You're testing each value `i` in in `leftMax` to `rightMax` inclusive against the entire array, which will bring the time complexity to O(number of houses * (max(houses) - min(houses))), which is probably not the intended solution.

Comment: Still in edited answer, I don't see any improvement in time complexity. You said about binary search, the code in your answer is not using that at all.